# How to change Content-Type for XQuery response?

Tags: xquery, xforms, exist-db

Adding images instead of code because it doesn't show up.

1. I have an xquery which forms webpage. It runs on exist-db.
2. This xquery calls another xquery with xforms submission:

   [image]
3. returnTable.xq returns an HTML table when run from browser directly

   [image]

In this case Content-Type in response is:
    [image]

4. You can see from submission that this HTML table should replace data in 'table' instance.
5. It does replace the data, but instead of HTML table I get a plain text.
   I use 
   `<xf:output value="instance('table')" mediatype="xhtml"/>` 
   to show the table on webpage. I tried mediatype xml, text/xml and others.

So, when it is replaced I got a plain text instead of HTML table on webpage.

[image]

Should be like this (which I get in a completely different way, but do not want to use it due to poor performance):

[image]

I think it happens because response's Content-Type is `Content-Type = text/javascript` instaed of `Content-Type = text/xml`:

[image]

[image]

Do you know how can I change this?

Comment: To make code show up in a list, indent it by four more spaces than you already had. To do this, you can put a single letter (I like `!`) on the line directly before the already-indented block, with no indentation, then select the whole block and the `!` and press CTRL+K or the button with braces on it.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for XQuery serialization options, which are [supported by eXist DB](http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/xquery.xml#serialization), but differ between XQuery 1.0 and XQuery 3.0.

XQuery 1.0 option to set the content type to `application/xhtml+xml`:

```
declare option exist:serialize "method=xml media-type=application/xhtml+xml";
```

For XQuery 3.0, you can use standard XQuery serialization options:

```
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";
declare option output:method "xml";
declare option output:media-type "application/xhtml+xml";
```

Comment: Thank you. The thing is that when I call the query which returns the table directly in the browser - it returns a proper XML and return type is text/xml, but when I call this query from another query with http POST it returns type text/javascript and XML tags are removed from response body. Adding those options does not change this behavior.

Comment: Where you now write `<xf:output value="instance('table')" mediatype="xhtml"/>` you should probably be writing `<xf:output value="instance('table')" mediatype="application/xhtml+xml"/>`.